# Sharing view models between activity and its fragment is not calling observable in the activity

Tags: android, mvvm

I am using view pager. I have created a shared view model for my activity and the fragments in my view pager. The problem is the observer in the activity doesn't get called when I set the MutableLiveData value in my view model.

I using following lines to initialise my view models

> 1. in activty: viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
> 2. in fragment: viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);

While debugging I found that my observer of the activity gets removed on the fragment's onCreated.

As far as I know both the fragment and the activity should have the same view model instance.

Comment: We need a bit more code, ideally enough to minimally reproduce the problem. Have you tried changing the first one from `of(this)` to `of(getActivity)` as in the example code https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: first one is the activity itself.

Comment: dunno sorry, someone's written it up here tho https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I found the answer though and it was just a silly mistake. I will be removing this question as it won't be helpful here.

Comment: You could also answer the question yourself, no question is silly and it might help someone else who does that same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the solution. I was creating a new instance of the observable in the activity and the fragment as well. Which was causing the instance that was created in the fragment to be called and the instance of the observable that I was observing in the Activity was getting replaced at the time of fragment creation.

Answer (score 0):

I use a different view model for each fragment and one for activity because the responsability of each is different and should be separated, so i would create a different view model. In case you want to use the same maybe you can use a bundle to pass the view model from activity to fragment